# Is there a way to detect if the user I am calling is already on another call or not?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to figure out of there is a way I can figure out if the user I am calling is on another call. Is there a way I can somehow detect that with broadcast receivers or some kind of notification mechanism.I know whatsapp does it. When you make a call to another whatsapp user and they are in a regular phone call you get the notification that the user is on another call. I wonder if there is an easier way to detect this? Any links or answers would be greatly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can!

If you have same application on both the devices, the caller and the receiver, it is possible.

You need to build notification like service, 
where you fetch the call state `getCallState()` of the other device, when the caller tries to connect/dial.

You can use the following:

[TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCallState())
[PhoneStateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)